# Extjs state manager - save state from a dynamic form

Tags: extjs, state-management

I have a form that I add on click new fields. **http://jsfiddle.net/Zb8DV/**
the user can add his input and click on save.
I want onsave event to store the state in the cookie.
Next time when he enter to the form, I want to load the state, generate the fields in put the values last time he entered to the form.
So if you look at the form bellow:
you click on "add field" and a new field will be generated, after you add fields and put values, I want to save the state and load it next time...

[image]

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Stateful',
    stateful : true,
    stateId : "MyFormState",
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'add field',
        count: 0,
        handler: function () {
            this.count += 1;
            var me = this;
            this.up("form").add([{
                "xtype": 'textfield',
                name: 'field' + me.count,
                fieldLabel: 'field ' + me.count
            }]);
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        margin : '10 10 10 100',
        text: 'Save form state on click here',
        handler : function(){alert("how do I load the panel with the state saved in cookie??")}
    }],

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your button handler you can get values from form with [`getValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getValues) method and then store values into cookies with [`Ext.state.Manager.set()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.state.Manager-method-set) method.

```
handler : function(btn){
    var form = btn.up('form');

    var values = form.getValues();

    Ext.state.Manager.set('formFieldValues', values);        
}
```

Restore form state from cookies you can in listener for form `afterrender` event. For getting form state from cookie you can use [`Ext.state.Manager.get()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.state.Manager-method-get) method.

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(form) {
        var values = Ext.state.Manager.get('formFieldValues');
        if (values) {
            console.log(values);                
            Ext.Object.each(values, function(key, value) {
                form.count += 1;
                form.add({
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'field' + form.count,
                    fieldLabel: 'field ' + form.count,
                    value: value
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle with complete example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/32e**

Comment: +1 excellent!!! can you please tell me if it is possible to save the textbox as well in the state? (I will not do it on cookie (-: )

Comment: What do you mean by "textbox"? The textfield label?

Comment: I mean, `form.add(value)` , value is the text box with value inside. meaning I dont want to build the form again, I want to save the textfield json in the state manager. thanks

Comment: I think that this is not possible. As I know ExtJS components does not have method which returns object serialized to JSON which can be easily restore. I think that the best approach will be store only data and create method for adding textfiled into the form and use it in both situation - when you are restoring form and when user click on add field button.